# Checking if Apache requires SSL pass-phrase

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd, openssl

I'm thinking about restarting a client's Apache server, but I'm reluctant to do so because I know he's currently running HTTPS and I don't want to get stuck with the server prompting me for the SSL Passphrase (which I don't have and he's not sure if there is one or not).

Is there a quick/easy way to check whether Apache will require the SSL pass phrase **before** restarting it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could check whether the private key is password protected by running

```
$ openssl rsa -in /path/to/private.key -check -noout
```

If this prompts you for the password, the key is obviously password protected.

Comment: +1 Thanks @Andreas. Worked a charm and responded with '`RSA key ok`'.